# get a previous array value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am making a php chat system and I would like to add a header for each day.

In order to achieve this I need a way to get both the current message date and the previous messgage date from my database, so I can use them in an if statement:

```
<?php if ($dtdate != $dtdateprev) : ?>
```

I am having a problem getting the previous entry date.

In order to get these values I use the following:

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $dtval=$row['dtdate'];
    $dtvalprev= **???**;
    $dtdate=date_format(new DateTime($dtval), "D d M Y");
    $dtdateprev=date_format(new DateTime($dtvalprev), "D d M Y");
?>
<?php if ($dtdate != $dtdateprev) : ?>
<div>Example Header</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div>Example Message Body</div>
<?php } ?>
```

So I need some help for $dtvalprev! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a side note, mysql_* functions will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0+, you should consider using PDO or mysqli_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the previous date using a query:

```
select t.*,
       (select dtdate
        from test t2
        where t2.dtdate < t.dtdate
        order by dtdate desc
        limit 1
       ) as prevdtdate
from test t;
```

Alternatively, you can query the database in date order:

```
select t.*
from test t
order by dtdate;
```

And use logic in php to remember the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$dtvalprev= '';//previous value initially blank
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $dtval=$row['dtdate'];

    $dtdate=date_format(new DateTime($dtval), "D d M Y");
    if($dtdateprev)// check previous value should not blank
        $dtdateprev=date_format(new DateTime($dtvalprev), "D d M Y");

    ?>
    <?php if ($dtdate != $dtdateprev) : ?>
        <div>Example Header</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div>Example Message Body</div>
    <?php 
    $dtdateprev=$dtval;// re-assign the current value
}
?>
```

Comment: For the second entry and the following, **$dtdateprev** when used in an _echo_ prints the current date and not the previous value. For the first it is null at it should be. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, if you `echo` the **$dtdateprev** then it will give the `previous value`

Comment: I have replaced `<div>Example Message Body</div` with `div><p><?php echo $dtdate; ?></p><p><?php echo $dtdateprev; ?></p></div>` and i get the following: `<div>Example Header</div><div><p>Fri 26 Oct 2012 13:08:31</p><p></p></div><div>Example Header</div><div><p>Sat 27 Oct 2012 14:02:09</p><p>Tue 06 Aug 2013 13:00:09</p></div><div>Example Header</div><div><p>Mon 05 Nov 2012 12:02:11</p><p>Tue 06 Aug 2013 13:00:09</p></div><div>Example Header</div><div><p>Mon 05 Nov 2012 12:04:54</p><p>Tue 06 Aug 2013 13:00:09</p></div>`. I also changed the date format to "D d M Y H:i:s".